# Inno setup postinstall check box

Tags: windows, checkbox, batch-file, inno-setup

Is there a way that check box is not shown to user or user cannot uncheck the checkbox? My purpose is I want to run a batch script at the end of installation and I must run it so I don't want this to be users decision.

Answer (score 4):

Declare this procedure in your [Code] section

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('YOUR APP PATH AND NAME OR IN YOUR CASE YOUR BATCH SCRIPT'), '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL,
     ewNoWait, ResultCode);
  end;
end;
```

this will execute your batch after you press the "finish" button.

Comment: Also useful with `ssPostInstall`

Answer (score 2):

Just don't add the `postinstall` flag.

For instance,

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\myfile.bat"; Flags: shellexec
```

Comment: Still have problem, I want it to be run last but with this flag it does not run last.

Comment: @abbas: It will run after the installation has completed, but before the final dialog is shown. That isn't late enough?

Comment: no it is not, because before that a file is being written and before it is written my batch code should not start

Comment: Written by what? If it's something your setup calls/starts, you should wait for it to finish, instead of presenting the "finsihed" prompt when it hasn't.